# Rules for creating preference objects

Tags: rally

What are the rules to creating preference objects using the WSAPI?

- Do you need to specify a workspace, project, or user or some combination?
- When do preference names conflict with other names?  Can you have the same Name field value but for a different user?
- I am seeing the following error when I try to create a second preference object:  Validation error: Preference.Value conflicts with NAME (where NAME is the value in the name field).  What triggers this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Yes, you need to specify one (and only one) of Workspace, Project, or User. This is the "scope" of the preference.
- You can specify the same name for different scope values. For example, all of these are valid:

  - Name: 'A', User: 'Bob', Value: 'some value'
  - Name: 'B', User: 'Bob', Value: 'some value'
  - Name: 'A', User: 'Larry', Value: 'some value'
  - Name: 'A', Workspace: 'WS1', Value: 'some value'
- But trying to create a new Preference with Name 'A' and User 'Bob' would fail, since that Name/Scope combination already exists.